# can't create a database in DBeaver

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, relational-database

I'm working with PostgreSQL using Dbeaver. To create a database, I need to create a new connection, so I select PostgreSQL in this window

[in this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiFJL.png)

then I press next and this window pops up

[window pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiQu5.png)

and no matter what I write in the User, Database or Password fields it shows the same error.

When I put "misha" in the Database field:

> FATAL: role "misha" does not exist

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXSxs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new role named `misha`.

I assume you are using GUI, if so you could just right click on `Login Roles` menu and create a the role.

Here's the query to do it manually :

```
CREATE ROLE misha LOGIN UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'misha'
  SUPERUSER
   VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

Comment: but then, when I execute the query it just shows disconnected from database error.